# How do I return one property OR another in Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'd like my query to return something like this:

```
n.property1? OR n.property2? as columnName
```

The use case is that I have two different node archetypes returning in one query, one node type doesn't have property2 and the other doesn't have property1, but that achieve the same purpose and I need them to return under the same column name. (For example, if a person could only enter a home phone number (n.home) or a cell phone number (n.cell), but you wanted it to return as phone (n.home? OR n.cell? as phone).)

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
COALESCE(n.property1?, n.property2?) as columnName
```

will return property1 if it exists else property2

Comment: Is there a need for the `?` on `n.property1` within the `COALESCE`?

Comment: Think so, if you don't have it you'll get a "property does not exist on node" error

Comment: Yes, you do need the ? Try START n=node:node_auto_index(name='Neo') 
MATCH n-[r:KNOWS*]-m 
RETURN coalesce(n.age,m.years?) AS age at http://console.neo4j.org